# apple mfi iap2 identification rejected

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, mfi

I was developing an usb audio device for ios.
And i use the "usb devcie mode"(my deivce is the USB host,apple is USB device),
compliance with apple offical doc:mfi accessory interface specification for apple device release R5.

I have pass the authentication,and get apple "StartIdentification" request.
When sent "IdentificationInformation" command with my identification. 
I get "IdentificationReject" for ID 15.(USBDeviceTransportComponent)

I have try just remove ID15's "USBDeviceSupportedAudioSamplerate" parmeter:6,7,8(enum value correspond to samplerate),and the "USB Device Mode Audio" command in ID6,ID7. And i get "IdentificationAccept".But i can't use usb audio whithout audio command now...

The rejected IdentificationInformation ID15 hex dump:
00 1C 00 0F //group header
00 06 00 00 // parmeter 0 header
0A 01 //component id
00 07 00 01 // parmeter 1 header
73 61 00 //name string
00 04 00 02 //parmeter 2 header(only header,means transport support iap2)
00 07 00 03 //parmeter 3 header
06 07 08 //samplerate enum val(32k,44.1k,48k)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After figuring out you hex dump data, I found the problem is in sample rate parameter. You need id3 parameter for each sample rate.

Correct hex dump :

```
00 24 00 0F //group header 
00 06 00 00 // parmeter 0 header 
0A 01       //component id 
00 07 00 01 // parmeter 1 header 
73 61 00    //name string 
00 04 00 02 //parmeter 2 header(only header,means transport support iap2) 
00 05 00 03 //parmeter 3 header 
06          //samplerate enum val(32k)
00 05 00 03 //parmeter 3 header 
07          //samplerate enum val(44.1k)
00 05 00 03 //parmeter 3 header 
08          //samplerate enum val(48k)
```